# Function calling itself not working (infinite loop, Javascript)

Tags: javascript, function, callback, definition, anonymous-function

I'm trying to wait and then get a message when all images in an array have completed loading (using .complete), per the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280049/javascript-callback-for-knowing-when-an-image-is-loading).  As such I set up an infinite loop like the below. however, when I run this I get an error that checkForAllImagesLoaded() is not defined.  This code is being run through a bookmarklet, and as such it's all wrapped up in an anonymous function construct (as below).  If I re-define my function and variable outside of that construct, it works.  But that seems to be a poor way to write a bookmarklet. How can I fix this so it will still recognize the function after the setTimeout?

```
(function() {

    //var images = array of images that have started loading

    function checkForAllImagesLoaded(){
        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            if (!images[i].complete) {
               setTimeout('checkForAllImagesLoaded()', 20);
               return;
            }
        }
    }

    checkForAllImagesLoaded();

})();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the function call, and take out the quotes. If you don't put the quotes, `setTimeout` gets a direct reference to the function which it can invoke later. However, if inside a string such as `"checkForAllImagesLoaded"` or `"checkForAllImagesLoaded()"`, then it will execute the code passed-in when the timeout occurs.

At that time, `checkForAllImagesLoaded` will be searched for in the global object (window) but it is not defined there, reason being why you're getting the `undefined` error.

Your code is wrapped in a self-calling anonymous function, and outside of it `checkForAllImagesLoaded` does not exist. So pass a direct reference to the function in your setTimeout call, instead of a string.

```
setTimeout(checkForAllImagesLoaded, 20);
```

[`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) can be called with either a function (and optional arguments), or a string containing JavaScript code:

```
var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(func, delay, [param1, param2, ...]);
var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(code, delay);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the () in the settimeout call.

`setTimeout('checkForAllImagesLoaded', 20);`

Comment: That won't work, since the browser will try to execute the equivalent of `eval('checkForAllImagesLoaded')` in the global scope, where there is no name `checkForAllImagesLoaded` defined.

Answer (score 1):

With your code, you set a number of timeouts per call. You should just set the timeout once per `checkForAllImagesLoaded()` call and perhaps increase the waiting period (20 milliseconds is just too quick). E.g.

```
function checkForAllImagesLoaded() {
  var allComplete=true;
  var i=0;

  while (i<images.length && allComplete) {
    allComplete=images[i++].complete;
  }

  if (!allComplete) { // Any incomplete images?
    setTimeout('checkForAllImagesLoaded()',1000); // Wait a second!
  }
}
```