# checking if image is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, asp.net, image, loading

I am using

```
if (document.getElementById('<%= MainImg.ClientID %>').complete) {
  hideLoadDiv();
}
```

to hide a div which indicates the image is not loaded yet,

but it hides before the image has finished loading and is shown, while the browser is giving me a message that the page is still transferring data from the server :S

Is there another function I can use to make sure that the image is fully loaded?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript callback for knowing when an image is loading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280049/javascript-callback-for-knowing-when-an-image-is-loading)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the onload event on the image iteself:

```
<img src="foo.jpg" onload="hideLoadDiv();" />
```

Update: looks like your question is a dup

Comment: @Miroo so add the onload in the code behind: `MainImg.Attributes["onload"] = "hideLoadDiv();";`

Answer (score 1):

javascript

```
img = new Image();
img.src = "foo.bar";
img.onload = function() {stuff();};
```

Comment: sorry what? i dont understand

Comment: the image i should check it's loading status is runat server so onload function can't be applied on it  :(

Comment: runat?? what does it mean? if this means running on than my next answer: what do you mean on running an image. image is not executable.

Comment: @fehergeri `runat="server"` means it a asp.net image control.

Comment: i dont know what is asp anyway :D he should re answer his question. i answered for the javascript stuff but i cant help in asp...

Comment: yeah but im saying this is notonly javascript and html problem.. and if i know this earlier i dont post this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {stuff();};
img.src = "foo.bar";
```

src should go last