# Can I change a asp control from image handler?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp page with a button on it that uses an image handler to show a jpg.  Can I disable a button on the page from the image handler base on what image is loaded.  for example if c:/x.jpg is loaded, disable the button.

Thanks
Charles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image handler will not be able to do anything - an image doesn't contain any scripts that can be executed.

You *can* check for the image loaded event in javascript and act on the value. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280049/javascript-callback-for-knowing-when-an-image-is-loading) SO question and answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is inherently impossible.

The image is loaded with a separate HTTP request that has nothing to do with the page.