# Is there any event that fires right before the browser request another resource such as image?

Tags: javascript, browser, monitoring, dom-events

We would like to measure how much time it takes the browser the get a resource from the network.
so for example if my page loads 10 images and 4 scripts I would like to know how much time it took the browser to load those resources from the network.

writing a browser plugin might work, but it's forces us to write different tool for each browser..what else can we do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript callback for knowing when an image is loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280049/javascript-callback-for-knowing-when-an-image-is-loaded)

Comment: it's not a duplicate, the main challenge is to identify when the browser sends the request.(start time)

Comment: @jbabey This is not a duplicate since this question is about an even before the resource is requested instead of when it is finished loading.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not believe that such a javascript/dom event exists.  This is why most proposed solutions you are going to see will involve browser plugins which expose this, or external tools, like DynaTrace AJAX Edition.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Speedtracer](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/speedtracer/) should give you this information. I believe it shows the start of the request and the total elapsed time.

If you're concerned about browser specific quirks, you'd likely need to do some inline logging with JavaScript.

---

A pretty basic script such as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var startTime = new Date().getTime();
</script>
<img src="yourimage.jpg" onload="console.log('new Date().getTime() - startTime')" />
```

ought to do the trick, but it's awfully invasive.

Comment: looking for some javascript I can add to the page and not an external tool or a plug-in.

Comment: the script that you added is problematic, it starts counting when the browser loads that script, instead of when the browser actually sends the request

Comment: Ah, I see what you're driving at. No, I don't believe the browser exposes an `onBeforeLoad` event to JavaScript.