# How to find the size of page downloaded in a webpage using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am writing a code to display a dynamic loader for a web page. I know the total download size of the webpage and hence if I can get the size downloaded for certain intervals I can display a dynamic loader with percentage.

Is there any way to find the size downloaded from dom in intervals using jquery. Thanks in Advance !

Comment: This link can help http://markmail.org/message/kmrpk7w3h56tidxs#query:jquery%20ajax%20download%20progress+page:1+mid:kmrpk7w3h56tidxs+state:results

Comment: Using just jQuery, no! Using jQuery to capture the downloaded amount from a serverside script or similiar, yes.

Comment: What is the main size of your page - scripts or images? If it's scripts you could insert loader updating callbacks into each them or into script-loader you use. If it's images you could be checking it using .complete property (http://stackoverflow.com/a/24201249/405623)