# Preload images without names of images

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, image

i'm looking for a script or a way to preload images before the page become full load. What i found are script where i have to write the name and the root of the images, i need something that load like:

Load all img of the page, after show the page, during the loading of the images to show a preload image ( like loading or something like that ).

It's possible?

I have alrady tried the script on the web, but i found just script where i have to put the name of the images in a array... i don't need it!

**I want that javascript load before ALL tag  ( without i set the name of the images ) of the page and than show the page!**

Comment: i want that javascript load before ALL tag <img> ( without i set the name of the images ) of the page and than show the page!

Answer (score 0):

jquery has a plugin called imageready.

https://github.com/weblinc/jquery-imageready

Ive used it many times, it should work as you expect

Answer (score 0):

Images will start being downloaded by your browser as soon as the DOM renders that part of your HTML. What you need to do is find a suitable animated gif very small size (few kilobytes) of a loading animation. Then have some javascript hide the image you want to show that is still getting downloaded by your browser. By using something like: [Javascript callback for knowing when an image is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280049/javascript-callback-for-knowing-when-an-image-is-loaded#280087) you will be able to check when an image has loaded, and the callback you can hide its associated gif and show the real image.

Comment: in your script i haave to write the name of the images, i want that javascript load before ALL tag <img> ( without i set the name of the images ) of the page and than show the page!