# how can i force script work after loading img?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have next script. It works before img load, thou i use method load.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slide-img img').load(function(){
    var height = $(this).height();
    var width = $(this).width();
    if (width > height) {
      $(this).attr('style', 'max-height: 100%');
    };
    if (height > width) {
      $(this).attr('style', 'max-width: 100%');
    };
  });
 });
```

how can i force script work after loading img?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280049/javascript-callback-for-knowing-when-an-image-is-loaded

Comment: You may want to check out some image-preload libraries for this purpose. You code only run when the DOM is ready. http://www.createjs.com/preloadjs may be overkill, but definitely is an option.

Comment: Your code seems fine. Check your selector is correct.

Comment: I'm not sure, but why is his `.load` function inside of `(document).ready`? I don't think it needs to be there.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kino45/jo82d6pw/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use window.load method(jquery):

```
$(window).load(function() {
// this will fire after the entire page is loaded, including images
});
```

Or use window.onload method(javascript):

```
window.onload = function() {
// this will fire after the entire page is loaded, including images
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! but it don't work too or i did mistake.
look here please - https://jsfiddle.net/kino45/jo82d6pw/1/

Comment: do you add jquery in your jsfiddle. Check my codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RaxyGQ

Comment: dont include your image load function, $(window).load take care of your image load. check my answers comment section.