# Tie into javascript load event for img tags

Tags: javascript, html

I am following this tutorial ( https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/performance-analytics ).

The gist of what is happening is on `img` load a timing mark is logged, I don't want to add onload to all my `img` tags for our entire website. I ruled out Jquery because it is measuring performance and I do not want to wait for the Jquery library to load because it will interfere with the timing measurements. Therefore I prefer to use Javascript. But pretty much what I am after is the functionality of the Jquery script.

```
$('img').load(alert('performance marking event, img loaded'));
```

This will allow me to leave all my img tags alone and insert a script that should relatively not affect my timing on  when img tags are loaded.

Devin

Comment: Do you know what `$('img').load(function() { alert('...'); })` would do? It goes through each `img` tag and attaches a `onload` event handler.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript callback for knowing when an image is loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280049/javascript-callback-for-knowing-when-an-image-is-loaded)

Comment: Mike C, wasn't that clear, I want that using Javascript only.

Comment: @DevinGleasonLambert I'm telling you that you have to use `onload`. jQuery uses `onload` inside of it. (jQuery is just JavaScript code)

Comment: @MikeC just explained to you what the `jQuery` method does behind the curtains, which is what you want to do.

Comment: But your question is a duplicate anyway. Refer to the link in the comments to find the answer to your problem.

Comment: Oh sorry, I am fine with techically using the onload functionality, what I want to avoid is replicating it in the HTML DOM 1000's of times.

Comment: @DevinGleasonLambert Don't insert it into the DOM directly. Get all of your images using something like `document.querySelectorAll('img')` then use a `for` loop to give them an `onload` handler.

Comment: Yes, my goal is to do something like this. Also I do not have the ability to wait to load the `src` attribute until after, I need to hijack the `img` tags and add the `onload` attribute.

Comment: @DevinGleasonLambert Dude. I literally just told you how to do that. If you don't know how to use a `for` loop then you need to do more JavaScript tutorials.

Comment: That's not my question, my response is, the other SO answer says you need to wait to assign the src attribute, I don't have that convience since they are set in other portions of the site, and I don't want to do a site redesign to make this work.

Comment: In other words, in the other answer, the assumption is that the dev can assign the `src` during the JS script, I am trying to hijack existing `img` tags and add an `onload` event

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, this is the method I went with following the example in: [Javascript callback for knowing when an image is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280049/javascript-callback-for-knowing-when-an-image-is-loaded)

Devin

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(i = 0; i< imgs.length; i++)
{
    attachMyLoadEvent(imgs[i]);
}

function attachMyLoadEvent(img)
{
    img.onload = function(){console.log('img loaded: ' + img.src);};
}
```