# JavaScript - opening new window in print mode after document is ready

Tags: javascript

I want to open a new window in print mode, after all images loaded(and the document is ready).
Here is my code:

```
var win = window.open();
//css ltr
win.document.write('<style>body { direction: rtl; unicode-bidi: bidi-override; }</style>');
//insert img
win.document.write('<img src="assets/imgs/logo.png">' + '<br>');
//insert txt
win.document.write(pdf);
win.document.write('<br>');
win.document.write('<img src="assets/imgs/buttomLogo.png">' + '<br>');
win.print();
win.close();
```

I had tried to use `onLoad()` but it print the document without the pictures:

```
win.onload = function () {
   win.print();
   win.close();                           
}
```

How can I open the document in print mode with all the images?
Fiddle - [printer](https://jsfiddle.net/7d2nfzbs/).

Thanks.

Comment: and if there are several images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Way 1 :** Try with below code. Added body tag before HTML start and added `onload` function on it and defined `window.print()` function in body `onload` function.

```
var win = window.open();
//css ltr
win.document.write('<style>body { direction: rtl; unicode-bidi: bidi-override; }</style>');
//insert img
win.document.write('<body onload="javascript:PrintMe()"><img src="assets/imgs/logo.png">' + '<br>');
//insert txt
win.document.write(pdf);
win.document.write('<br>');
win.document.write('<img src="assets/imgs/buttomLogo.png">' + '<br><body>');

function PrintMe()
{   
    win.print();
    win.close();
}
```

**Way 2:** Use image event listner `image.attachEvent("onload"`

```
var win = window.open();
//css ltr
win.document.write('<style>body { direction: rtl; unicode-bidi: bidi-override; }</style>');
//insert img
win.document.write('<body onload="javascript:PrintMe()"><img src="assets/imgs/logo.png">' + '<br>');
//insert txt
win.document.write(pdf);
win.document.write('<br>');
win.document.write('<img src="assets/imgs/buttomLogo.png">' + '<br><body>');
image.attachEvent("onload", function() {
    win.print();
    win.close();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Pretty hacky - but that way I did this to wait for images to load was write in a `script` tag to the new window, and add a listener for images:

```
mywindow.document.write('<script type="text/javascript">var img = document.getElementById("js-company-logo"); var src = img.src; img.addEventListener("load", function() { window.print(); window.close(); }); img.src = ""; img.src = src;</script>');
```

I also had to set the `src` of the images each time (an issue with Chrome caching the images and not displaying on print previews after being used the first time)

Comment: Trying and posting the result.

Answer (score 1):

onLoad is not the best solution.
There is a good info about onLoad in:
[Javascript callback for knowing when an image is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280049/javascript-callback-for-knowing-when-an-image-is-loaded)