# Detecting orientation of images with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to find a way to detect the orientation of images (landscape or portrait).

The HTML simply contains a few img tags with source already filled in. The script should then detect the orientation and add the images to dynamically created divs acting as thumbnails.

The script I've been using is this (found it on here somewhere)

```
    for (i = 0; i < pics.length; i++) {
      pics[i].addEventListener("load", function() {
        if (this.naturalHeight > this.naturalWidth) {
          this.classList.add("portrait")
        } else {
          this.classList.add("landscape")
        }
     })
    }
```

Now this usually works fine when first loading the page. When refreshing however, it behaves erratically, adding the right class to some images and not adding any class at all to others.

I also tried this

```
for (i = 0; i < pics.length; i++) {
  var img = pics[i];
  var width = img.naturalWidth;
  var height = img.naturalHeight;
  if (height > width) {
    img.classList.add("portrait")
  } else {
    img.classList.add("landscape")
  }
}
```

Which also works unpredictably. All images get a class added to them, but some get the wrong one.

I'm guessing the problems might come from the images not completely loading before the script runs and thus the script not being able to measure them correctly, but I'm not sure. Anyhow, I don't really know how to fix it either.

To give an idea of what I'm going for, here's a link to the page:
http://pieterwouters.tumblr.com/

Any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: Is your script at the top or bottom of the page?

Comment: This scrip should be executed adter the page has finished loading. How do you execute it now?

Comment: It's at the bottom of the page, or at least as far down as tumblr will allow (since it adds some automatic script of its own), so in theory the images should load before the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the image is already loaded when you call `pic.addEventListener("load", ...)`, the load event handler will not be triggered. You should call it if `pic.complete` is true, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24201249/1009922).

```js
var pics = document.querySelectorAll("img");
var pic;

for (i = 0; i < pics.length; i++) {
  pic = pics[i];
  if (pic.complete) {
    // The image is already loaded, call handler
    checkImage(pic);
  } else {
    // The image is not loaded yet, set load event handler
    pic.addEventListener("load", function() {
      checkImage(this);
    })
  }
}

function checkImage(img) {
  if (img.naturalHeight > img.naturalWidth) {
    img.classList.add("portrait")
  } else {
    img.classList.add("landscape")
  }
}
```

```css
img {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.landscape {
  border-color: red;
}

.portrait {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<img src="//placehold.it/50x100">
<img src="//placehold.it/200x100">
```

Thanks to Ricky. I borrowed the image links and the style attributes from his answer.

Answer (score 2):

For a safer but more expensive approach you could duplicate the images in memory and add the corresponding class.

```js
const images = [...document.querySelectorAll('img')].map(el => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let img = new Image();
    img.addEventListener('load', function() {
      const {
        naturalHeight,
        naturalWidth
      } = img;
      if (naturalHeight > naturalWidth) el.classList.add("portrait");
      else el.classList.add("landscape");
      img = null; //GC
      resolve();
    });
    img.src = el.src;
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.landscape {
  border-color: red;
}

.portrait {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<img src="//placehold.it/50">
<img src="//placehold.it/50x100">
<img src="//placehold.it/200x100">
<img src="//placehold.it/50x60">
<img src="//placehold.it/10x30">
<img src="//placehold.it/50x20">
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help!

ConnorsFan, based on your earlier comment I added a part to take into account already loaded images and came up with this

```
// forgot to mention this part in my original post
var pics = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for (i = 0; i < pics.length; i++) {
    pics[i].addEventListener("load", function() {
        if (this.naturalHeight > this.naturalWidth) {
            this.classList.add("portrait")
        } else {
            this.classList.add("landscape")
        }
     })  
     if (pics[i].complete) {
         if (pics[i].naturalHeight > pics[i].naturalWidth) {
             pics[i].classList.add("portrait")
         } else {
             pics[i].classList.add("landscape")
         }
     }
 }
```

Which works, your solution seems a bit more elegant though so I'll probably use that one.