# Is there a way to load some images first, then (or meanwhile) others in HTML?

Tags: jquery, html

Is there a way to load some images first, then (or meanwhile) others?

Here the HTML structure, I want all first images **start to loading** on the first time, order doesn't matter, when the image loaded doesn't matter (first image can be loaded after other images due to big size)

```
<ul>
  <li><img /></li> <!--first image-->
  <li><img /></li>
  <li><img /></li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li><img /></li> <!--first image-->
  <li><img /></li>
  <li><img /></li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li><img /></li> <!--first image-->
  <li><img /></li>
  <li><img /></li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li><img /></li> <!--first image-->
  <li><img /></li>
  <li><img /></li>
</ul>

...
```

Comment: If you simply use raw HTML tags, you won't. But you can "inject" the images throught Javascript according to what have been loaded.

Comment: Append images with JavaScript and add a timeout to the images you want to delay.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot with raw HTML. Although, you can add images through javascript depending on what have been loaded. Something like this:

```
<ul id="list">
  <li id="first-image"><img /></li> <!--first image-->
</ul>
```

Then, on javascript:

```
var list = document.getElementById('list');
var firstImage = document.getElementById('first-image');
var listItem = document.createElement('li');
var otherImage = document.createElement('img');

firstImage.onload = function () {
    listItem.appendChild(otherImage);
    list.appendChild(listItem);
};
```

I've not tested the code, but it's something like this. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

**Edit:**

I was reading a little more about it, and I think there's a little issue with the code below. Using this way, the event is going to trigger when the DOM element has been loaded, and not neccesarily the image *per se*. I've found another solution:

```
var img = document.querySelector('img')

function loaded() {
  alert('loaded')
}

if (img.complete) {
  loaded()
} else {
  img.addEventListener('load', loaded)
  img.addEventListener('error', function() {
      alert('error')
  })
}
```

Source: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280049/javascript-callback-for-knowing-when-an-image-is-loaded).

Answer (score 0):

There is a jQuery plugin that controls the order of image load: https://github.com/AlexandreKilian/imageorder

this might help you in your situation.