# How to animate header background image onload event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, keyframe

I want my header background image should animate on load. And I have done this

```css
.header_area{
    background-image: url(../img/mobility_solutions.jpg);
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position: center center;
    animation: shrink 3s;
}

@keyframes shrink {
    0% {background-size: 110% 110%;}
    100% {background-size: 100% 100%;}
}
```

This is working but not when the page is loading for the first time in a browser. How can I align it to happen on load event always?

You can check it here- http://demogenesystel.mywebkitchen.com/

Comment: You will have to use JS for that. CSS does not have the logic to determine whether an image has been loaded or not. The JS logic, however, is simple: (1) listen to the onload event fired from the image, likely loaded in a hidden image element (2) once loaded, add class to `.header_area` which defines animation. This ensures that the animation does not apply/run on pageload, but only after the image is successfully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hidden img tag with link to this image. And after it will load set background-url. While it loading can use svg spinner (for example https://loading.io/) and css class with opacity:0

```
//javascript:
var hiddenImg = $('<img />').addClass('hidden')
hiddenImg.attr('src', ....)
hiddenImg.bind('load', function(){
  $(this).addClass('show'))
  var yourTarget = $('..');
  yourTarget.css('background-image', 'url(' + your url + ')');
})
//css
img.hidden {  opacity: 0; }
```

PS: you don't need to use jQuery for this 
[Javascript callback for knowing when an image is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280049/javascript-callback-for-knowing-when-an-image-is-loaded)

Comment: Thank you for the help @AlexeyKuznetsov. But it's a background image how to use the CSS  indicating the 'img' can you help me to understand this?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to use some simple JS to detect the `background-image` URL of the element, and load it as part of a dummy `<img />` tag so that you can attach an onload event to it to detect if the same image has been successfully loaded.

The `background-image` extraction requires some simple replace, because it actually returns the entire `url(/path/to/image)` string, sometimes with optional inverted commas. Therefore, we can use a pattern that matches this:

```
^url\(["']?(.*?)["']?\)$
```

Basically the pattern attempts to match `url(` at the start, with an optional inverted comma, followed by anything in between, then by another optional inverted comma and a closing bracket `)`. The first capturing group will be your background-image URL. [You can see how it works here](https://regex101.com/r/x0WUzu/1).

When we have this, we assign the `src` attribute to the dummy `<img />` element this value. When this element fires the `load` event, we add the class `.header_area--animate`, which applies the animation you have defined for the `.header_area` element.

It is of course possible to write this entire logic in JS, but since you have tagged jQuery, why not? ;)

```js
$(function() {
  $('<img />', {
    src: $('.header_area').css('background-image').replace(/^url\(["']?(.*?)["']?\)$/gi,'$1')
  }).on('load', function() {
    console.log('Image loaded, adding animation');
    $('.header_area').addClass('header_area--animate');
  });
});
```

```css
.header_area {
  background-image: url("http://deelay.me/1000/http://placehold.it/1000x500");
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position: center center;
  
}
.header_area--animate {
  animation: shrink 3s;
}

@keyframes shrink {
  0% {
    background-size: 110% 110%;
  }
  100% {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header_area">

</div>
```

Comment: Can't get into it : (  can you please give me the exact source so I can use it by copy paste Terry ?