# Get the Height from The Image that get from A Html File by JavaScript Fetch Api

Tags: javascript, jquery

These are my codes:

a.html

```
<div class="pic-box">
    <img src="a.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

index.html

```
<div class="get-box"></div>
```

index.js

```
const pageUrl = './pages/a.html',

fetch(url).then(function(response){
    if (response.ok) {
        return response.text();
    }
}).then((data) => {
    $('.get-box').html(data);
    const imageHeight = $('.get-box img').height();
    console.log(imageHeight);
});
```

I want to get the height of the image, but it showes me it 0.
How could I get the true height?

Comment: is there a image in .get-box.... try **console.log( $('.get-box).find('img') )**

Comment: I suspect that the image hasn't been loaded yet - try binding to to the complete event for images, and check the height there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280049/javascript-callback-for-knowing-when-an-image-is-loaded

Comment: try   *$('.get-box img').eq(0).height();*

Comment: I use `if (img.complete) {...}`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I use `$('.get-box img').eq(0).height();`, and it still shows me 0.

Comment: `if img.complete` won't work because it won't block until it is complete. That's why you need to bind to the event.

Answer (score 0):

You should append `a.html` source to `<div class="get-box"></div>` element or replace:

a.html

```
<div class="pic-box">
    <img src="a.jpg" alt="..." onload="imageLoaded(this)" />
</div>
```

If you use jQuery:

```
function imageLoaded(element){
    const imageHeight = $(element).height();
    console.log(imageHeight);
}

const url = './pages/a.html';

$.ajax({ url: url })
  .done(function(html) {
    // Append
    $(".get-box").append(html);

    // or Replace
    // $(".get-box").replaceWith(html);           
  });
```

Comment: Using jQuery Ajax  to load at first time, it still shows me 0.

Comment: You need to wait until the image has loaded to have access to the width and height data.

Comment: If I can use `jQuery(window).load(function() { … })` again in `.done()`?