# Change image src with a smooth transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to change the src of an existing image with a series of other images. I have got this working but the transition is terrible and not smooth at all. I guess this is because it abruptly loads the new image AFTER the initial one is faded out rather than at the same time.

Is there any clever way to make this transition completely smooth?

```
var images = new Array ('image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg');
var index = 1;

function rotateImage()
{
  $('.Parallax-host').children(':first-child').find('.Index-page-image img').fadeTo(1000,0.30, function() 
{
$(this).attr('src', images[index]);

$(this).fadeTo(500,1, function() 
{
  if (index == images.length-1)
  {
    index = 0;
  }
  else
  {
    index++;
  }
});
});
} 

$(document).ready(function()
{
 setInterval (rotateImage, 5000);
});
```

I dont have access to the markup here so it needs to be a jquery only solution.

Comment: does it happen every time or only first load

Comment: Every time because it does the same function as it loops through the images.

Comment: you're going to need a second image element that has the next image already loaded. position it behind the first one and reveal it while the other fades out.

Comment: I was thinking that. But not sure how to do it. Would love to see an example if possible?

Comment: @dgeare that's the point

Comment: create a div with display none and and img tag inside it. Than load the image after image load run your function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280049/how-to-create-a-javascript-callback-for-knowing-when-an-image-is-loaded this post will be helpful

Comment: Here is a codepen I made. It might be a bit more complicated than you need but it does the trick (on chrome anyway): https://codepen.io/dmgig/pen/PJxrjX

Comment: I'm kind of looking for a full working example. Surely this has been done before?!

Comment: @j00m There are definitely jquery background switcher plugins that do this.

Answer (score 0):

here's something to get you started.

```js
const images = ["https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQQnY5_NI7cYhnEqnNWcyX29B6x71CmUp1Xs_uFCkIrWEzuBhXf","https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/562466745340817408/_nIu8KHX.jpeg","https://images.pexels.com/photos/20787/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350"];
let curImage = 0;
function rotateImage(){
  let next = document.createElement('img');
  next.onload = function(e){//wait for the image to load
    document.getElementById('img_container').insertBefore(next, document.querySelector("#img_container img"));//insert new image before the previous (for stacking order)
    $('#img_container img').eq(1).fadeOut(1500, function(){
      $(this).detach();//remove the faded out img
    });
  };
  next.src = images[curImage];
  curImage = (curImage + 1) % images.length;
}
setInterval(rotateImage, 5000);
```

```css
#img_container{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#img_container img{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  min-width:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='img_container'>
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/20787/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" />
</div>
```