# Create JavaScript function on onload image

Tags: javascript, onload, create-function

Is it possible to create a function in the onload event of an image? Is there a method that makes this possible?

```
<input type='text' name='data' onblur='myFunction(this.value)'>
<img src='img/none.gif' onload="function myFunction(text){alert(text)}">
```

the image and field will be loaded by an ajax function.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280049/how-to-create-a-javascript-callback-for-knowing-when-an-image-is-loaded

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a JavaScript callback for knowing when an image is loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280049/how-to-create-a-javascript-callback-for-knowing-when-an-image-is-loaded)

Comment: @PardeepDhingra — Not a duplicate of that. The code already runs a callback when the image is loaded. The question is about creating a function from within that callback.

Comment: @AnkitKumar — Not a duplicate of that. The code already runs a callback when the image is loaded. The question is about creating a function from within that callback.

Comment: @Quentin has answered your question. May i know the reason why you want to do so.

Comment: The context is different, the event is inside the IMG tag

Comment: I am developing a system for working with access control boards, the boards can be of different models and the devices for reading card, biometrics or control work differently on each board.To unify my control of registered devices I need a single structure in my database
Because the fields are different in each situation and are loaded with information from a database, passed through an ajax function to form the fields.I need javascript functions differentiated in each situation. So to do this I make each set of fields that is loaded create their own script to interact with the sensors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is using a function declaration, so you are defining the `myFunction` variable *only* within the scope of the `onload` function (so it isn't in scope when you try to call it from the `onblur` function).

So you *can*, you just need to explicitly assign it to be a global variable.

```html
<input type='text' name='data' onblur='myFunction(this.value)'>
<img src='https://static.jsbin.com/images/dave.min.svg' onload="window.myFunction = function myFunction(text){alert(text)}">
```

… I can't think of any <strike>good</strike> use case for this though.

Comment: Tks Quentin, perfect solution.

Comment: It is a complex system where the functions for sending commands to the control cards require different fields for each situation. The main control system reads only 1 field, so the function created in the image will aggregate the values of the available fields to pass the value in a single location. All data is created with ajax.