# Angular 7 - Load images before changing route

Tags: html, angular, routes, angular2-routing

I'm currently working on a portfolio. My intention is to only change the route ("portfolio" and its child route "all" which is displayed immediately) as soon as the images on that specific route are fully loaded. When the route was clicked as progress bar from Angular Materials shall be displayed.

Since I'm a beginner with angular I unfortunately can't provide any code, but my app-routing.module.

Browsing the internet I found a similar question, which I didn't really understand:

> https://forum.vuejs.org/t/load-images-before-changing-route/11479

**App-Routing.Module:**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'about', component:  AboutComponent},
  { path: 'portfolio', component:  PortfolioComponent, children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'all', pathMatch: 'full'},
      { path: 'all', component: AllComponent},
      { path: 'wedding', component: PortfolioweddingComponent},
      { path: 'adventure', component: PortfolioadventureComponent},
    ]},
  { path: 'book-me', component:  BookMeComponent},
  { path: 'book-me/wedding', component:  WeddingComponent},
  { path: 'book-me/adventuresession', component: AdventuresessionComponent},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'}), RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Tells us if  images are loaded from the assets folder within the app or hosted in some other domain ?

Comment: @JoelJoseph They are loaded from the assets folder.

Comment: dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280049/how-to-create-a-javascript-callback-for-knowing-when-an-image-is-loaded?