# Size of an image upon page loading is incorrect -- too small

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple images on a page and this code:

```
//main image
<img src="/my_image.png" id="main_img" />

//other images
<img .... onclick="setMainImg(this)" />



<button onclick="getSize()">get size</button>



//js, at the bottom
var mainImg = document.getElementById("main_img");

function getSize() {
  console.log(mainImg.width + "x" + mainImg.height + "\r\n");
}
```

When the page loads, it prints something like 33x16

After I click on different images:

```
  //js
  function setMainImg(img) {
    mainImg.src = img.src;
  }
```

it begins printing the corrent values in the console:

```
448x354
```

and something like this. Even when I click the same first image(!), it prints a different, 10 times bigger, size.

Why? How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get size after image loading, so you should set variable of your image whenever you click.

```js
var mainImg;

function getSize() {
  mainImg = document.getElementById("main_img");
  console.log(mainImg.width + "x" + mainImg.height + "\r\n");
}
```

Comment: how will that ensure that "after image loading" has happened?

Comment: @hohaf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280049/how-to-create-a-javascript-callback-for-knowing-when-an-image-is-loaded