# I do not understand the load event on the image tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to put the load event on my `img` element.

When I check on the jQuery documentation for the load event, I can see:

[image]

If I put my event like this :

```
$( window ).on( "load", function() {
   // My window is loaded and I can see my img by console.log
   console.log('img');
});
```

But if I try as shown in the documentation:

```
$( "img" ).on( "load", function() {
    // My event is attached but it can't load the console.log
    console.log($(this));
});
```

How can I use the `onload` event on the `img` tag ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Try using that code inside $(document).ready(function() { })

Comment: @jcarrera — the image might load before the document is ready

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] (which should show where the script is in relation to the image). Helpful debugging approaches would include adding an error event listener as well as a load event listener and logging which elements $(“img”) matches when it runs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I run a JavaScript callback when an image is loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280049/how-can-i-run-a-javascript-callback-when-an-image-is-loaded)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this can help:

```
<img id="book" alt="Book" src="book.png">

<script>
  const image = document.getElementById("book");               
     
  image.addEventListener("load", () => {
    console.log("image loaded successfully!");
  });
        
  image.addEventListener("error", () => {
    console.log("image loading error");
  }); 
</script>
```

Comment: @Tyler2P, good day happy to see it work for you. thanks and love to accept the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, i think i found my problem.

When my tag script is put on the head tag, and i put my load event on the document.ready, the load event is not trigger.
It seems i have to cheack with image.comple first beacause the image is already loaded.

But if i put my tag script at the end of the body, my event is trigger without the image.comple.

Strange like behavior?

For prevent the error best way is :

```
  if (img.complete) {
    // if complete do first
  } else {
    img.on('load', function(){
    // else put event and do my action when trigger
    }) ;
  }
```