# showing a preloading gif until all the images is fully loaded?

Tags: jquery, image, loading

I want de add preloading of all images of website ( with class="img-loading" )

I find this code

Jquery:

```
$('img').css('opacity', function() {
  $(this).wrap("<div class='img-loading'></div>")
  return '0';
}).load(function() {
  var img = $(this);
  $(this).unwrap();
  $(this).animate({
    opacity: 1
  }, 500);
});
```

And CSS:

```
.img-loading {
    background: url('/img/loading.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat;
}
```

THE RESULT is that the gif appears but is not hidden after to display the images source

Where is the error in these codes and how can I change the code so that it works

Comment: You appear to using the `.load` *event* which was **removed from jquery in 3.0** (partly for this very reason): https://api.jquery.com/load-shorthand.

Comment: According to [this (perhaps old) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280049/how-can-i-run-a-javascript-callback-when-an-image-is-loaded) some browsers don't implement `load` event and if the image has **already loaded** when you add the event handler, it clearly won't fire, which is probably your case here.  So you either need to check if it's already loaded or don't set `src=` until you've added the event handler.  See the linked question for more info.