How do I use content-visibility to stop loading of off-screen inline images?
<div
  style="content-visibility: auto; aspect-ratio:2609 / 1598; background-image:url(data:image/avif;base64,AAAAHGZ0eXBhdmlmAA...EgAAAAAAAAA=);background-size:100% 100%;"
>
  ...
</div>

The key thing to note is that it has content-visibility: auto; and that it has a background image that loads base64 encoded image.
Given that it has content-visibility: auto, I would expect that off-screen inline images are not loaded. However, if you load the page (you can try it here), you will see that it actually loads those images. You can tell by looking at the Network tab:

I would expect that just like the images referred to by URL, the ones with data:image would not start loading until they are deemed visible.

I'm not sure what you mean by an inline image. I see only a background image. Could you describe how you are ascertaining that the background images are being loaded regardless of how 'far' the element is from the viewport?

Provided more context.


About the Question
You want to implement a blur effect on an image until it has fully loaded.

Approach
To achieve this effect, I utilized a div that initially displays a blurred overlay. Once the image is fully loaded, the overlay is hidden.

Code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Blur Effect on Image Load</title>
    <style>
        #imageContainer {
            position: relative;
            width: 600px;
            height: 400px; 
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #myImage {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            object-fit: cover;
            display: none; /* Initially hide the image */
        }
        .overlay {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%);
            filter: blur(10px);
            transition: filter 0.3s ease, opacity 0.3s ease;
        }
        .loaded {
            filter: none;
            opacity: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="imageContainer">
        <img id="myImage" src="" alt="Loading image...">
        <div id="overlay" class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
    
    <script>
        function waitForImageToLoad(imageElement) {
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                imageElement.onload = resolve;
            });
        }

        var myImage = document.getElementById('myImage');
        var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
         var newImageSrc = "https://media.istockphoto.com/id/2026162051/photo/portrait-of-a-young-latin-female-student-using-laptop-on-the-bench-on-campus.jpg?s=2048x2048&w=is&k=20&c=MynQ_nHkQEZ6TxK_uqz_TyZ8B3lLUmFoG1WXhLJNxEQ=";

        waitForImageToLoad(myImage).then(() => {
            // Image has loaded.
            myImage.style.display = 'block'; // Show the image
            overlay.classList.add('loaded');
        });

        // Set the image source to start loading.
        myImage.src = newImageSrc;
    </script>
</body>
</html>

This solution uses JavaScript to handle the image loading process, applying a blur effect until the image is fully loaded and then removing the blur effect.


Nope ,I reviewed this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48208414/24895210, then came up with this solution.
This is the predefined format I use for uploading solutions on LeetCode. Before uploading any solution, I always do my research, and the comments in the code are for understanding purposes for those who are genuinely here to learn.
Please give it a try to see if it resolves your issue. If you have any genuine concerns, I'd be happy to assist further.

Please make it a code snippet next time so user can play around with it and tweak things as they want. A better approch whould be to use after/before pseudo classes instead of an overlay div for better reusability (good shit tho)

This does not answer the question but instead suggests a completely different technique for placeholder images.

I can’t see how this stops the images being loaded, which is what the question is asking. Can you explain?
